# Postman visualization: Can I create conditional statements?

Tags: postman, handlebars.js

I am returning a JSON body from an API using postman.  I am using the visualization feature of Postman to create a template to organize and loop through the data.  https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/visualizer/

Question: Can I create conditional statements?  Test for the value of certain elements?  The handlebars features do not seem to work.

Example:

```
{{#each response}} {{#if name = 'abc'}}
<td>ABC</td>
{{else}}
<td>{{name}}</td>
{{/if}} {{/each}}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding to Dannys answer:

https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/7373#issuecomment-601402891

As of now custom helpers are not supported so you have to do the if logic inside your script:

### Example:

https://www.getpostman.com/collections/d3a91ce456800d061156

you can import this collection by clicking import link in postman

### Explanation:

### set get url as:

https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2

### test script as :

```
template = `<table bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>

        {{#each response}}
            {{#if George}}
            <tr>
                <td>Found george</td>
                <td>{{email}}</td>
            </tr>
            {{/if}}
        {{/each}}
    </table>
`;
data =pm.response.json().data
data.map((a)=>   a[a.first_name]=true)

// Set visualizer
pm.visualizer.set(template, {
    // Pass the response body parsed as JSON as `data`
    response: data
});
```

**If you read the handle bar documentation :**

https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html

> You can use the if helper to conditionally render a block. If its
> argument returns false, undefined, null, "", 0, or [], Handlebars will
> not render the block.

so here we are hacking this behavior , i am creating a key in the data object with same name as the value i am checking for

if the value doesn't exists then the element will be undefined else it will pass.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `if` blocks but not quite like that, as the syntax is slightly different. You can find more information about how these work here:

https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html

> You can use the if helper to conditionally render a block. If its argument returns false, undefined, null, "", 0, or [], Handlebars will not render the block

Comment: We've tried that I believe, is it for sure something that works in postman?

Comment: Depends how you're using it, it it's like the way you mentioned then no.  There's an example of how it could be used on the link I provided. You also have JS in the sandbox to use though so you could combine the two if that's an option.

Comment: You're basically just dealing with the response data but using handbars in the template to manipulate it, you could do all that outside of the template in plain JS and then use that within the template.